# AsyncStorage in redux thunk, action not dispatching

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to use `asynchStorage` to `dispatch` actions when I recieve the data:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("loggedIn")
        .then(this.props.dispatch(isLoadingCredentials(true)))
        .then(
            data =>
                data
                    ? this.props
                          .dispatch(setCredentials(JSON.parse(data)))
                          .then(this.props.dispatch(navigate("Month")))
                          .then(
                              this.props.dispatch(
                                  isLoadingCredentials(false)
                              )
                          )
                    : this.props.dispatch(isLoadingCredentials(false))
        );
}
```

Using redux `connect`

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

I get the error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: _this2.props.dispatch(...).then is not a function
TypeError: _this2.props.dispatch(...).then is not a function
```

How can I dispatch actions when I receive the data?

Comment: By using react-redux `connect` or redux's `bindActionCreators`, for example?

Comment: `this.props.dispatch(setCredentials(JSON.parse(data)))` - how would this return a resolve/reject value from a `Promise`?

Comment: I need to dispatch an action when set credentials is complete somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining `mapDispatchToProps` and passing it as a second argument, alongside `mapStateToProps`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  isLoadingCredentials: (loadingCredentials) => (
    dispatch(isLoadingCredentials(loadingCredentials))
  )
})
```

You could use [bindActionCreators](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/bindactioncreators) as [Pegase745](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588498/pegase745) suggested. It's shorthand for the above.

Then pass it through to your component via `connect`.

`connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen)`

You would then use your function like so, notice there's no `dispatch` property.

```
componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("loggedIn")
        .then(() => this.props.isLoadingCredentials(true))
        ...
}
```

You probably want to refactor your call to `AsyncStorage` because you're calling `isLoadingCredentials(true)` once the Promise has been fulfilled.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.isLoadingCredentials(true);
  AsyncStorage.getItem("loggedIn")
    .then((user) => {
       // You have your User, do as you wish
       // Add setCredentials and others to mapDispatchToProps
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.props.isLoadingCredentials(false); // Error
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is this a `thunk`?